# Persistent "less info" preference across all SE sites

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, preferences

I prefer the "less info" profile view. When I click the "less info" or "more info" button to change the view, the site should remember this. Please make this preference persistent across all StackExchange sites — either on the server side as part of my profile, or at least locally in my browser.